# Identifying a specific binary number with bitmask

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I am trying to identify states in a CANopen motor controller using the following bit masks.

```
//x means that the value of the bit doesn't matter and is set to 0
NOT_READY_TO_SWITCH_ON = 0,    //xxxx xxxx x0xx 0000 - Not ready to switch on (decimal value = 0)
SWITCH_ON_DISABLED = 64,       //xxxx xxxx x1xx 0000 - Switch on disabled (decimal value = 64)
READY_TO_SWITCH_ON = 33,       //xxxx xxxx x01x 0001 - Ready to switch on (33)
SWITCHED_ON = 35,              //xxxx xxxx x01x 0011 - Switched on (35)
OPERATION_ENABLED = 39,        //xxxx xxxx x01x 0111 - Operation enabled (39)
QUICK_STOP_ACTIVE = 7,         //xxxx xxxx x00x 0111 - Quick stop active (7)
FAULT_REACTION_ACTIVE = 15,    //xxxx xxxx x0xx 1111 - Fault reaction active (15)
FAULT = 8,                     //xxxx xxxx x0xx 1000 - Fault (8)
```

I am receiving a number on which I apply the bit mask to try to identify the states above but I can't wrap my head around how it should be done.

The following code is my attempt to implement it in C#:

```
foreach (State s in (State[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(State))) //State[] contains all bitmasks above
{  
   var v = valToCheck & (ushort)s; //valToCheck is the number to apply the bitmask to
   if ((valToCheck & (ushort)s) == (ushort)s) //Apply the bitmask and compare it to bitmask
   {
      stateList.Add(s); //Add to list for trouble. shooting
   }
}
```

But doing it this way I end up with, instead of one, a bunch of states which is, I guess, expected since applying for example, the bitmask 0 (NOT_READY_TO_SWITCH_ON) will always yield true for any number (when using and).

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is this simply not possible using bit masks? I am also unsure if it is correct to set the bits marked with x to 0 in the masks.

Comment: Those values don't look to me as if they are intended to be interpreted this way. Maybe there is an underlying set of flags, which they are combinations of. Or maybe not even that. Is there some documentation of these values?

Answer (score 1):

You're right - you can't test for 0 with masks; presumably the intent is that all zero has special meaning that only matches this flag, so you would special case it by testing for *equality* with zero instead:

```cs
if (thingToLookFor == 0) return value == 0;
```